# MATE - Missing Suspend and Hibernate buttons, pressing power button shutdowns system immediately

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate, mate

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.5 with all updates and with MATE 1.8.1 from PPA.

With recent update I can't suspend or hibernate from `mate-power-manager`.[image: see image]

If I press the power button the system shutdowns immediately with no prompts.
`upower -d` reports the following:

```
Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.15
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate    yes
```

System suspends and hibernates normally with `pm-suspend` and `pm-hibernate`.

Why this happens? What should I do to recover power button and GUI functionality?
On which component should I report bugs?

Installing ubuntu-mate-desktop does not solve the problem. There are no broken packages in my system, debsums report no errors.

Comment: I reported against mate-power-manager [bug 1419321](http://launchpad.net/bugs/1419321).